# Share service with http data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http

I dont want to do the same http call accross controllers so i want to make a service wich fetches the data and returns data to the controller i tried to do this

the controller:

```
App.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, ngDialog, Notification, validationSerivce, dataService) {
    $rootScope.pageName = '1-search';
    $scope.type = 'delivery';

    $scope.searchZip = function() {
        //vars
        var zip = $scope.zip;
        var type = $scope.type;

        //check empty zip
        if (typeof zip === "undefined" || zip === null){
            Notification.error({message: "no zipcode entered", delay: 3000});
        } else {
            //validate zip
            if (typeof validationSerivce.validateZip(zip) == "string") {
                Notification.error({message: validationSerivce.validateZip(zip), delay: 3000});
            } else {

                //set spinner and blur
                $scope.setBlur('add');
                $scope.setSpinner('show');

                //get the data
                console.log(dataService.getSearchData(zip,type));
            }
        }
    };
});
```

and the service looks like this:

```
App.factory("dataService", function($http) {
    return {
        getSearchData: function(zip,type) {
            //Get request
            $http({
                url: url+"/search?zip=" + zip + "&type=" + type,
                method: 'GET',
                headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            }).success(function(data){
                return data;
            }).error(function(err){"ERR", console.log(err)});
        }
    };
});
```

but the return is 'undefined'

the api returns data.... how can i do this the best way?

Comment: Think about these: is AJAX synchronous or asynchronous? When is the success callback executed? If returning data from a call to $http was possible, why wouldn't the $http service do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no return statement in your `getSearchData()` function. Return the result from $http and access it as a promise. e.g.

```
dataService.getSearchData(zip,type).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: i have done this but then i get ypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.searchZip (SearchCtrl.js:33)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12345)

Comment: that's because your not returning anything from getSearchDate(). Return the result from $http. e.g. `return $http(...)`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
App.factory("dataService", function($http) {
return {
    getSearchData: function(zip,type) {
        //Get request
        return $http({
            url: url+"/search?zip=" + zip + "&type=" + type,
            method: 'GET',
            headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function(data){
            return data;
        }).error(function(err){"ERR", console.log(err)});
    }
};
});
```